# funcion de javascript se manda a llamar dos veces

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datatable

Buen dia

Estoy trabajando con la siguiente DataTable:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando la funcion child de DataTable para desplegar informacion adicional del registro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el boton (mas, menos) de la tabla que se encuentra al inicio de cada registro tiene una clase details-control la cual uitilizo para llamar a la funcion que despliega los detalles del registro. Esta es la funcion:

```
$(document).on('click', '#table tbody tr td.details-control', async function () {
    var tr = $(this).parent();
    var row = $('#table').DataTable().row(tr);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
        console.log('cerrar')
    }else {
        // Open this row
        $.each($('.shown'), function () {
            $('#table').DataTable().row(this).child().hide()
            $(this).removeClass('shown');
        });
        row.child(await format(row.data())).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
        console.log('abrir')
    }
});
```

Este es mi metodo format, el cual mando a llamar para mostrar la informacion adicional del registro:

```
async function format(d) {
            return await getRequeriments(d.request.idRequest).then(data => {
                var buttons = '';
                var subTable = '<table class = "subTable">';
                data.forEach(element => {
                    if (d.estatus == 'En Proceso' && element.requeriments.fkTypesStatus == 1 &&
                        (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()' ||
                    @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
                        buttons = '<button class= "btn btn-success btn-circle realizado" title="Realizado"> <i class="material-icons">done</i></button>' +
                            "&nbsp;" +
                            '<button class= "btn btn-danger btn-circle noRealizado" title="Rechazar"> <i class="material-icons">close</i></button>'
                    } else if (d.estatus == 'En Proceso' && element.requeriments.fkTypesStatus == 3 &&
                        (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()' ||
                    @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
                        buttons = '<h6 class ="text-success">REALIZADO</h6>';
                    } else if (d.estatus == 'En Proceso' && element.requeriments.fkTypesStatus == 5 &&
                        (d.request.wiwResponsable.trim().toLowerCase() == '@Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["wiw"].ToLower()' ||
                    @Request.Cookies["PFEPCoockie"]["idRole"] < 4)) {
                        buttons = '<button class= "btn btn-danger btn-circle comments" title="Ver Comentarios"><i class="fas fa-sticky-note"></i></button>';
                    } else if (d.estatus == 'Rechazado') {
                        buttons = '<h6 class = "text-danger"></h6>';
                    }
                    subTable += '<tr class = "headers">' +
                        '<th hidden>' + 'ID' + '</th>' +
                        '<th hidden>' + 'idReq' + '</th>' +
                        '<th>' + 'Numero de parte' + '</th>' +
                        '<th>' + 'Pool' + '</th>' +
                        '<th>' + 'Estacion' + '</th>' +
                        '<th>' + 'SA1' + '</th>' +
                        '<th>' + 'SA2 Actual' + '</th>' +
                        '<th>' + 'SA2 Solicitado' + '</th>' +
                        '<th>' + 'Razon' + '</th>' +
                        '<th>' + 'Estatus' + '</th>' +
                        '</tr>' +
                        '<tr class = "content">' +
                        '<td hidden class ="id">' + element.requeriments.idRequisition + '</td>' +
                        '<td hidden class ="idReq">' + d.request.idRequest + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + element.requeriments.itemNumber + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + element.requeriments.pool + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + element.requeriments.station + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + element.requeriments.SA1 + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + element.requeriments.lastSA2 + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + element.requeriments.currentSA2 + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + element.reasson + '</td>' +
                        '<td class ="buttons">' + buttons + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>'
                });

                subTable += '</table>'
                return subTable;
            });
        }
```

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Mi funcion se esta mandando a llamar dos veces 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago click en el boton para desplegar la informacion adicional en consola se imprime dos veces la palabra abrir y cuando vuelvo a hacer click en el boton para que cierre la informacion se imprime en consola la palabra cerrar y despues la palabra abrir.

Investigando en internet me encontre comentarios que mencionaban que esto se debia a que estoy mandando a llamar la funcion dentro de un modal o algo similar.

Estoy utilizando ASP.NET y mostrando mi tabla con ayuda de una vista parcial, tal vez esta sea la causa del porque esta ocurriendo esto.

¿Existe alguna manera de prevenir la segunda llamada que viene de VM7187?

Comment: Amigo podrías compartir el código de como esta el método de donde cargar los datos de la tabla que incrustas es decir el html

Comment: @Horacio Xochitemol Acabo de agregar el meto que utilizo para generar mmi subTabla Saludos!

Comment: bueno la verdad tampoco entiendo el porque lo unico que se me ocurre es que implementes el event.preventDefault();, para que se detenga.

Comment: Ya intente con e.PreventDefault y no funciono